# Run only in a selected range, not in the entire document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use
    `set SelectedRange =selection.range` to define the selected range I choose. I hope to find and replace something only in the selected range. But this works.

```
    SelectedRange.Font.Bold = True
    For i = 1 To 3
    SelectedRange.InsertAfter Text:="Hello " & i
    Next
```

```
    With SelectedRange.Find
   
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Color = 12611584
    .Text = "^p^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p*"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
   
    End With
    SelectedRange.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

And that runs in the entire document.

I need the replacement only in the selected range, not in the entire document.
I tried     `Set tempRange = SelectedRange.Duplicate` and performed the replacement in the tempRange, then copy temprange into selectedrange. However, it didn't work; it replaced text in the entire document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code searches the entire document because you have told it to continue past the selection with `.Wrap = wdFindContinue`

Change that line to `.Wrap = wdFindStop`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's useful. I mistakenly thought that "wdFindContinue" would continue within the selected range. Now I understand that "wdFindContinue" continues within the entire content.

Comment: @Rachel1208 Would you like to accept this answer to close your question? And please remember to refer to the document more when you use something to do your code first.